# A question about simplifying

Tags: simplifying-expressions

From basic examination, the following expression

```
Integrate[Abs[a - x], {x, 0, n}]
```

appears to simplify fully to

```
5 n - n a + a^2
```

However, using Mathematica, I get something containing both Re and Im. Note that n, a, and x are all Reals. How do I use Mathematica to derive 5 n - n a + a^2, on the assumption I am right. If I am wrong, I would also like to know why.

Comment: You have to let MMA know about your assumptions; otherwise everything is assumed to be complex: `Integrate[Abs[a - x], {x, 0, n}, Assumptions -> {a, n} \[Element] Reals]`. None of those expressions match yours, but they are closer.

Comment: Under what assumptions did you get your result. I think the result depends on the relation of a and n and n should appear quadratically.

Comment: Use `Assuming` so that assumptions are available to both `Integrate` and `FullSimplify`, i.e., `Assuming[n > 0 && Element[a, Reals], Integrate[Abs[a - x], {x, 0, n}] // FullSimplify]`